# Is an image avatar in bottom navigation allowed?

Tags: android, ios

Does anyone know if Google has issue with putting an image avatar in the bottom bar navigation? I haven't seen anything specific on this, but noticed that Instagram on Android do not have the avatar whereas on iOS they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that you cannot do it , the default `BottomNavigation` has no built in methods for you to directly do it. But if you are targeting the items in bottom navigation , the `MenuItem` has icon property that takes a bitmap, so you can do something like

```
                navigation.menu.findItem(R.id.my_account)?.icon = BitmapDrawable(resources, your_bmp_res)
```